# ZOOM crashes when entering the room - Ubuntu 22.04 1

Tags: 22.04, crash, zoom-meeting

I installed Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on a new machine and downloaded Zoom from the official website.

Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)

Zoom crashes when entering the room, and none of the solutions provided in several posts work for me.

Comment: Sounds like a good question for Zoom support.

Comment: THank you David. How should i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I removed the old one using:
`sudo snap remove zoom-client`

Note: I tried
`sudo apt remove zoom`per zoom website instructions, but zoom could not be found. I guess I had initially installed via snap.

I then downloaded the .deb file directly from zoom, installing using Software Install. It seems to work fine now.

You can test that it worked here: https://zoom.us/test